# Should `keepalive_timeout` be removed from Nginx config?

Tags: nginx, keepalive

**Which is the better configuration/optimization: to explicitly limit the `keepalive_timeout` or to allow Nginx to kill keepalive connections on its own?**

I have seen two conflicting recommendations regarding the `keepalive_timeout` directive for Nginx. They are as follows:

```
# How long to allow each connection to stay idle; longer values are better
# for each individual client, particularly for SSL, but means that worker
# connections are tied up longer. (Default: 65)
keepalive_timeout  20;
```

and

```
# You should remove keepalive_timeout from your formula.
# Nginx closes keepalive connections when the
# worker_connections limit is reached.
```

The [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#keepalive_timeout) [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout) for `keepalive_timeout` makes no mention of the automatic killing, and I have only seen this recommendation once, but it intrigues me.

This server serves *exclusively* TLS-secured connections, and all non-encrypted connections are immediately rerouted to the `https://` version of the same URL.

Answer (score 14):

> Nginx closes keepalive connections when the worker_connections limit is reached.

That's true.

- [src/core/ngx_connection.c:l843](http://hg.nginx.org/nginx/file/0a567878254b/src/core/ngx_connection.c#l843) - `ngx_drain_connections();`
- [src/http/ngx_http_request.c:l3042](http://hg.nginx.org/nginx/file/0a567878254b/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#l3042) - `ngx_reusable_connection(c, 1);`

Comment: So what is the better configuration?